# Google REcaptcha not showing

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have the following in my `<body>`

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="some-key (original is right)">
```

and this on my `<head>`

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

but nothing is shown, either on firefox or chrome... Is this a known issue?

Comment: is there any script errors in console?

Answer (score 10):

make sure that `<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>` is the last thing before closing of head tag.
That fixed same problem for me

Answer (score 9):

Just hit this obstacle, and in my case it was due to AngularJS. It's not limited to Angular, any library which binds the elements after page load can cause the Google reCAPTCHA to not show up since the element just does not exist by the time Google's code is being executed.

To solve this, first make the render explicit and supply a function to execute when the reCAPTCHA  loads:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaOnload&render=explicit' async defer></script>
```

Now, add a unique ID to the container, e.g.

```
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site key here"></div>
```

Then in the custom function wait for the element to actually exist:

```
var _captchaTries = 0;
function recaptchaOnload() {
    _captchaTries++;
    if (_captchaTries > 9)
        return;
    if ($('.g-recaptcha').length > 0) {
        grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
            sitekey: 'site key here',
            callback: function() {
                console.log('recaptcha callback');
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    window.setTimeout(recaptchaOnload, 1000);
}
```

This will keep trying for 10 seconds, until it finds the element, then render the reCAPTCHA into it.

Comment: where to call this function?

Comment: @RajatTyagi it should be called automatically when the API loads, you send it to the API via the url: `?onload=recaptchaOnload&render=explicit`. I didn't test in recently, doesn't it work anymore? If you add `console.log` lines to the function you don't see the output? (Or direct debugging via dev tools)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any content blockers activated in your browser, for example Ad-Block Plus or uBlock origin.

Disable these, refresh the page and submit the form again.

Answer (score -1):

The issue I had was that it was showing most of the time but occasionally it wouldn't and I'd have to submit the form (and trigger validation) for it to show. Adding `?render=explicit` to the script tag fixed it for me.

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>`

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render

Answer (score -3):

I just had this on a system that has stricter browser settings.
Adding `*.gstatic.com` to the trusted list resolved it

I also added `*.google.com` and `*.google-analytics.com`

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score -4):

Change:

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

I don't know if that's just a typo, if it isn't, adding the `https:` would definitely solve your problem.

Comment: `adding the https: would definitely solve your problem` There's no definitely about that; `//www.google.com/...` is a protocol-relative URL. If @Fane's document was being served from an `https` source, it'd be identical.